# How do I make an exclusive rather than inclusive query with named scopes in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I've created an application that finds service providers based on multiple services passed to it. This is done via has many_through so there is a join object. Basically, if a user asks for service providers with Service A and Service B my scope returns service providers who offer either BOTH Service A and Service B or other service providers who provide either Service A or Service B. Instead of this we'd like to limit it to only providers who provide BOTH services.

My scope looks like this:

```
  named_scope :with_services, lambda { |services| {
      :conditions => ["services.id IN (#{services.map{|s| s.id}.join(', ')}) 
                        AND service_options.service_owner_type='ServiceProvider' 
                        AND service_options.service_owner_id = service_providers.id"],
      :include => [:services, :service_options]
    }
  }
```

As you can see I'm using the IN operator to do this. But IN is like saying "get me any provider who has service A or service B" when what I really want is "get me any service provider who has both service A and service B."

Is it possible to do this type of filtering in a single query or would I need to do a compound query or simply loop through the results and remove them from the list if they do not support all of the required services?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can probably do it by providing the list of services for each of Service A and B.

So either amend the scope to take two lists:

```
:conditions => ["services.id IN (service_a) AND services.id IN (service_b)"]
```

You might even actually be able to call the scope twice

```
 Model.with_services(service_a).with_services(service_b)
```

Also at no extra cost, you can shorthand your array manipulation to find the ids:

```
services.collect(&:id).join
```

&:id is the equivalent of a block using "|o| o.id".

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a shot. One problem I forgot to mention in the question is that this is variable. So you could have 1 service or 5 services passed in. 

Would the best method be to map the services and generate that snippet of SQL? Like this:

:conditions => ["#{services.map{|s| 'services.id IN('+s.id+')}.join(' AND ')} ..."]

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try this method I get nil. I believe it's because a given ID can't be equal to or IN two mutually exclusive values. It looks like it almost requires a compound query. I may just have to use a for loop to parse through the results :-\